# Controller HTTP methods not working with rspec due to I18n.locale error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, internationalization, rails-i18n

So I'm trying to test controller methods with rspec tests, but they aren't working due to some issue with I18n? I'm getting this error message:

```
masonscott@amory:~/Workspace/cs169/cs169-smileygo$ rspec spec/controllers/reviews_controller_spec.rb 
F..

Failures:

  1) ReviewsController POST #create Review can be created
     Failure/Error: I18n.locale = env.http_accept_language.preferred_language_from(available)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `http_accept_language' for {}:Hash
     # ./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:22:in `set_locale'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:595:in `process'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:64:in `process'
     # /home/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:501:in `post'
     # ./spec/controllers/reviews_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01243 seconds (files took 1.96 seconds to load)
3 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/reviews_controller_spec.rb:6 # ReviewsController POST #create Review can be created

Coverage report generated for RSpec to /home/masonscott/Workspace/cs169/cs169-smileygo/coverage. 5 / 18 LOC (27.78%) covered.
```

What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What might be the issue here?

The issue would seem to be that you're calling [ActionController::Metal#env](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-i-env), an `@_env` variable hasn't been set, and you're being returned an empty hash, which doesn't respond to the `http_accept_language` method, but I don't think that knowledge will solve your problem.

It looks like you're using the [HttpAcceptLanguage gem](https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language), and looking at [its README file](https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language/blob/master/README.md), it looks like that if you're going to use the `http_accept_language` method in a controller, you don't need to use it against `env` unless you're writing Rack middleware.  Here is [the example from the README file](https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language/blob/master/README.md#example):

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_locale

  private
    def set_locale
      I18n.locale = http_accept_language.compatible_language_from(I18n.available_locales)
    end
end
```

Try changing your code to be like the example (ie removing `env`) and see if that works.